# How does github keep a loaded page while changing URLs?

Tags: url

https://github.com/ether/pad/tree/master/etherpad

If you click on that, then go to "bin", the URL changes, but the page doesn't reload.. how is this possible? It's not #'d!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is some new html5 candy: [history api](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html).  Also, here is an [article](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) where the github team explains the full implementation.